# Branch Based Development working with our Jenkins Automated Testing Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, trunk

Trying to progress test automation in the team. The development team have started trunk based development. They are worried the new automated smoke tests will fail all the time (due to their feature development often being incomplete) and our Jenkins board with always be RED (making it pointless). Has any one come across this issue or a fix for it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the principle of [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) to your test codebase, so that certain tests don't run until a feature is toggled on. The principle is simple enough that you could roll your own implementation, or depending on the language you use, there are frameworks that manage feature toggles, including in your test code. [Togglz](http://www.togglz.org/documentation/testing.html) is one such example for java.